# preg_replace ranged out - compilation failed

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

**In my code:**

```
$c = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9áčďéěíňóřšťúůýž_-:().,;!?]#i', '', $_POST['c']);
```

**I get this error:**
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 40

IDK where could be the error.

Comment: What are you trying to do? remove any non-alpha numeric chars?

Comment: try this: `$c = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9áčďéěíňóřšťúůýž\_\-\:\(\)\.\,\;\!\?]#i', '', $_POST['c']);`

Comment: @LatheesanKanes nope I wanna, allow only the ones which are set. It's regex for textfield which is for comments.

Comment: @LatheesanKanes well that was the problem - escaping that chars. Solved my problem.

Comment: @LatheesanKanes: There're no needs to escape all these characters as they are inside a character class.

Comment: @M42 changed according the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this way:

```
$c = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9áčďéěíňóřšťúůýž_\-:().,;!?]#i', '', $_POST['c']);
```

you need to escape `-` inside square brackets `[..]` because it's treated as interval specifier

Comment: Or put it at the begining or at the end of the character class. Nevertheless +1.